# Replace entire row of a 2D array with another 1d array

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, multidimensional-array

I am trying to replace an entire row of a 2d array with another vector. 
My code is currently as follow:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    int imax = 5;
    int jmax = 5;
    double x[imax][jmax] = {0.0};
    double a[imax] = {1,2,3,4,5};
}
```

In other words, now my x is a matrix with 5x5.  How do I add/append/rewrite the 1st row of X with my a vector?

Thanks

Comment: Not legal C++. Change the declaration of imax and jmax to const int. Have you studied for loops yet?

Comment: Yes, I've done for loops. Is there anyway to do this with for loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

imax and jmax should be const to make that code legal. Anyways, one obvious possibility is to copy elements one by one like this:

```
for ( int j = 0; j < jmax; j++ ) {
    x[row][j] = a[j];
}
```

Another way is to use memcpy. That should be faster in normal circumstances, however, you rely on the assumption that the square bracket [] operator was not overloaded. Also you only can overwrite one row this way, not a column, so be careful when and where you use that.

```
memcpy( x[row], a, sizeof(a) );
```

('row' is your variable where you put the index of the row you want to replace)

Answer (score 1):

One way to copy the row "without a loop" is the [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) standard library algorithm.

```
std::copy(a, a + imax, x[0]); // x[0] is the first row
```

The algorithm contains the loop. Depending on the implementation this might emit a single call to `memcpy` or `memmove` instead.